# Why does my clutch pedal squeak

Tags: honda, civic, clutch

My clutch pedal squeaks on its way in and out. I was hoping it was the pedal itself, but when I got under the car it sounded like it's coming from under the engine, where I presume the clutch is located.

The car is a 2003 Civic sedan.

Comment: Does this happen both when the engine is running and when it is not?

Comment: @CharlieRB Further investigation required. Will try to get back to you soon.

Comment: @CharlieRB so much for 'soon'--sorry! Turns out it was happening with the engine running and not, and with the transmission in neutral and in gear. I believe I've fixed it (temporarily) by WD40-ing the rod the goes from the clutch pedal through to the engine compartment. I'm guessing it's supposed to be a fairly tight fit, but it's not any more--possibly from many winters of salty boots. I'll probably white-lithium-grease it if the WD40 proves to be a good temporary fix. There's some squeaking still coming from somewhere farther away from the driver's seat, so I may have more to do.

Comment: Check the slave cylinder where the cable mounts into the boot. After I changed mine, I forgot to lube the cable ball and now its squeaks when actuating the clutch. :)

Comment: Try to remove the slave cylinder from the clutch and put some grease on the tip of the cylinder. That solved my clutch squeak! (different car though)

Answer (score 1):

The squeak.. if not from the pedal, cable or clutch slave cylinder is likely from either the clutch cover fingers or release bearing/return spring. Whilst the squeak itself is not likely a serious issue. If the clutch has been installed for a long time it could be a sign that it is becoming worn and the squeaking perhaps down to the amount of clutch dust in the bell housing/clutch casing. If the clutch is working well though, no slipping or stiffness in the pedal operation etc, I would just monitor the squeak.. If it becomes more noticeable or changes in some way then its time to have mechanism/clutch inspected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (different car, though), the culprit was the clutch fork rubbing against a nearby metal part, probably the casing. (Clutch fork is the lever sticking out of the gearbox which is pushed by the clutch slave cylinder).

After I removed the clutch fork boot and sprayed some lubricant inside, the clutch pedal became silent and easier operated, too.

You may find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ya3I9s9J2A) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well look at the most simple solution, and try spraying the mechanical elements with silicone spray, safe for plastic clutch master cylinders. Could just be friction outside of the cylinder, if your door creaks you don't replace the door.